# With query string go here, without go there, .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made a static image of a website and link the html files through a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ static/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^stuff$ static/stuff.html [L]
```

etc. I know, this is not the most clever way but it works.
Now the problem: I would like that

```
domain.com/?format=feed&amp;type=rss
```

is handled again by the index.php of the cms that still lives in the root directory. My attempts like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !feed=
```

were not successful - the request is always only appended at the redirected static file.

#### How could I achieve that the feed request is indeed processed by the cms?

My background is that although elaborate caching mechanism exist, none of them is even comparably responsive as static files for shared hosting. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Closest as I come seems

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?format=feed
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ static/%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L,QSA,R=301]
```

But this leads to a trailing slash too much when directed to the static version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just test for `format=feed`. No further context needed

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !format=feed
```

or you can do it the other way round and explicitly rewrite to `index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=feed
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
```